# Generate Power off of several motors at once

Tags: voltage, motor, generator

So in working on a project, I am considering generating power using several small 12V motors (made for DIY toy cars, very cheap on amazon) or by using one bigger electric scooter motor (24V, 250W, generally expensive). I am wondering if I could generate the same amount of power from a few small motors as I could from the big motor in a similar amount of time?

If so, could all of the small motors spin off of the same wheel (might move this to another question later...)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other things being equal, one 100 watt motor will have better efficiency, lower friction, better everything really, than 10 off 10 watt motors. Exactly the same goes for motors used as generators.

This is due to a larger motor having better geometry (tighter air-gap engineering) and better scaling (power handling and losses go up at different powers of the size).

One big motor will use fewer mounting screws than a handful of small ones as well.

One word of warning, don't use a car alternator if you want an efficient generator. They are used in an application where spare power is 'free', cooling is plentiful, so are built small and cheap, at the cost of lousy efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Large motors/generators are more efficient than smaller ones. These devices are made from large lengths of copper wires. The smaller devices use thinner wires. Thinner wires have more resistance to flow of electric current. Therefore more power is lost as heat if resistance of the wire is high. So it would pay off to use expensive but bigger motor.

Though a dc-motor works well as dc-generator, a purpose built generator would be more efficient. There are consideration for required rpm to efficiently get output from the generator. Getting output from a ac-motor would be more difficult.

Comment: by purpose built generator do you mean like a device with a sprocket or something that when spun generates electricity?

Comment: I meant an electric device that is designed as inverse function of motor. It may not have a mechanical prime mover to rotate the shaft.

Comment: got it, thanks for your answer. I don't have enough points on this website to upvote, but I would upvote your  answer if I could.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all your proposed motors large and small are permanent magnet brushed DC .Having them on one shaft is a good idea because then there wont be any complications in combining the outputs .The multiple small motors will be fine .The efficiency of the large motor will be greater but not by a huge amount because really all the motors you are discussing are classified as small.The small motors need to spin faster so if wear rate is going to be an issue think big .The small motors could be connected in some sort of redundancy scheme which could be relevent in high reliability applications .The faster spinning needs of the small motors Vs the slower rpm of the big motor means gearing ramifications .The speed of your prime mover could influence your final choice.